# Умный указатель в MinGW

Tags: указатели, mingw, кроссплатформенность

Есть необходимость переписать билдоровский код содержащий умный указатель:

```
//переменная для сохранения ссылки на Recorder
    TComInterface<IRecorder> FRecorder;

__fastcall TTestForm::TTestForm(IRecorder* pRecorder)
    : TForm( (Classes::TComponent*)0)
 {
FRecorder = pRecorder;
int count = FRecorder->GetTagsCount();
}
```

под MinGW.

Под MinGw получилось следующее:

```
#include <memory>
//переменная для сохранения ссылки на Recorder
std::unique_ptr<IRecorder> FRecorder;


bool STDMETHODCALLTYPE TTestPlugin::create(IRecorder* a_pOwner)
{

FRecorder = a_pOwner;
int count = FRecorder->GetTagsCount();
return true;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где допущена ошибка? Заранее спасибо

Comment: `FRecorder.reset(a_pOwner);`

Comment: А разве это правильно давать юникпойнтеру внешний указатель? Впервые встречаю такое применение.